# using phantomjs with RSelenium on windows 7

Tags: r, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am trying to use PhantomJS with RSelenium and seem to be having trouble:

```
require(RSelenium)
RSelenium::startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "phantomjs", extraCapabilities = list(phantomjs.binary.path =    "C:/Users/home/Desktop/phantomjs-1.9.8-windows/phantomjs.exe"))
remDr$open()
```

This results in:

```
$class
[1] "org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException"

$additionalInformation
[1] "\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown"
```

My `sessionInfo()` is below:

```
$class
[1] "org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException"

$additionalInformation
[1] "\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown"
```

**UPDATE**:
Unfortunately the solution below does not seem to work:

```
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
Error:   Summary: UnknownError
         Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
         class: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

Comment: the information above is already an indication of failure: the driver is unknown and an exception is caught. `open()` opens a browser and not a particular url

Comment: thanks for picking up on this. This issue was fixed on the dev branch. I will look to update the version on CRAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was fixed https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/commit/462ff26eb0e5578181b80cb5bc002ac1e8e68306. Can you try the following:

```
devtools::install_github("ropensci/RSelenium")
require(RSelenium)
psPath <- "C:/Users/home/Desktop/phantomjs-1.9.8-windows/phantomjs.exe"
RSelenium::startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "phantomjs"
                      , extraCapabilities = list(phantomjs.binary.path = psPath))
remDr$open()
```

UPDATE:

This appears to be an issue with the new 2.44 selenium server and ghostdriver for now you can drive phantom directly without a Selenium Server until the issue is fixed upstream or you can use an older version of Selenium Server (2.43 was working with ghostdriver):

```
# DRIVE phantomJS DIRECTLY
require(RSelenium)
# devtools::install_github("ropensci/RSelenium") # if the latest dev version is not currently installed
psPath <- "C:/Users/home/Desktop/phantomjs-1.9.8-windows/phantomjs.exe"
pJS <- phantom(pjs_cmd = psPath)
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "phantomjs")
remDr$open()
# pJS$stop() # to close phantom server
```

Comment: ok let me give that a shot. this is a separate question so i can make it such if that helps: do you have documentation on exceptions that can be thrown or some sample code with `trycatch`?

Comment: just tried it: unfortunately that did not work as hoped

Comment: Can you file an issue on https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues and I will look into it.

Comment: sure, will file it now

Comment: Looks like its an issue with the new Selenium server and ghostdriver https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/397 . I have committed an update to github which should allow you to drive phantomjs directly with a custom path.